# "Failed to instantiate file from module: The specified list does not exist." when deploying file through module

Tags: list, provisioning, module

I am trying to deploy two files to a custom list. I created two features for this: one that holds the list definitions along with the module and one that contains the list instances. Both are in the same package.

However, I always get the above error when deploying the files with the attribute "Type" set to "GhostableInLibrary". I already tried numerous things like moving the URL to the module/each file element to no avail. In the URL, the List is "ActivityReports" and "Templates" is a subfolder in the list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module RootWebOnly="FALSE" Name="Templates" Url="Lists/ActivityReports/Templates" Path="Templates">
    <File Url="Template1.xlsx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="FALSE" />
    <File Url="Template2.xlsx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="FALSE" />
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

Anybody see anything wrong my Elements.xml file?

Answer (score 2):

Remove "Lists/" from your module's `Url` parameter.

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module RootWebOnly="FALSE" Name="Templates" Url="ActivityReports/Templates" Path="Templates">
    <File Url="Template1.xlsx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="FALSE" />
    <File Url="Template2.xlsx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="FALSE" />
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

**Update:**
Just re-read your question. You write this Module is in the feature holding the List Definition - That's just the definition. It's the List Instance feature you want to include this module in.
You cannot add stuff to lists/libraries that does not exist yet.

Comment: I still get the same error :(

Comment: @LeonidasFett Chech my update.

Comment: even after moving the module to the list instance feature, I get the same error

Comment: @LeonidasFett Does your Templates module come after List Instance in the feature?

Comment: the module is at the very bottom of the feature while the ActivityReports instance is one position above it.

Comment: I just tried to add the files to the "Documents" document library because this list should surely exist. However, I still get the same error

Comment: @LeonidasFett And what happens if you add it to a separate feature?

Comment: still the same. it seems that sharepoint is stuck somewhere. but I also recreated both the web application and the site collections, without any improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing Type="GhostableInLibrary" to Type="Ghostable" in the elements.xml file. This fixed the issue for me.

[MSDN discussion related to this problem](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/27ac36ca-3d3a-47eb-9fc6-ee1b1846b8a3/failed-to-instantiate-file-defaultaspx-from-module-projectportalhome-the-specified-list-does?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy)

[Blog post confirming the fix](http://rajeshch999.blogspot.com/2011/08/failed-to-instantiate-file-from-module.html)